# How to retrieve value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my js I have a var in which I have stored innerHTML.
The var is having value something like

```
                <h2>headline</h2>
                <div>....</div>
                 ...........
```

Now I want to retrieve value of h2 tag..what I am doing is

```
           $(myvar).find("h2").text()
```

but its not working...what should be the exact syntax?
EDIT:

```
                 alert(myvar)=<h2>headline</h2>
                               <div>....</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are we supposed to know what `myvar` is?

Comment: "not working" is a little vague... do you get any error messages?  Also, your `<h2>` tag is not properly closed - is that the same in your real code?

Comment: myvar contains the innerhtml
u can say alert(myvar) will give u <h2>headline<h2>
                <div>....</div>
                 ...........

Comment: @ChaosPandion: it looks like `myvar` is a string containing the html in the first code block.

Comment: @Andy E's head - alert( $(myvar).find("h2").text()) is coming as blank

Comment: I wonder if that has to be added to the dom first ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` method will not work for this case, because it gets the *descendants* of each element in the current set of matched elements (the `h2` and the `div` in your example).

You can simply use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) *(available on jQuery 1.3.2)*:

```
var myvar ="<h2>headline</h2>" +
           "<div>....</div>";

alert($(myvar).filter('h2').text()); // headline
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/omago/).

Answer (score 0):

Find() returns a collection of nodes. Use first():

```
h2text = $(myvar).first("h2").text();
```

Comment: You would be correct, except that text() at worst concats the text of each matched element, which means that his code should work. Something else is wrong here and we need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to something like this.

```
<div>
    <h2>headline</h2>
    <div>....</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you see if it fixes your issue?

Answer (score 0):

generally would make more sense to wrap the contents of your var in a div as proposed by ChaosPandion.

if that's not possible, you can try this...

```
<script>
  var myVar = '<h2 id="test">heading</h2><div>stuff</div>';
  var jVar = $(myVar);

  alert($(jVar.get(0)).text());
</script>
```